# Android webView Load in Background

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app which i want to open a webview 
right now i am loading the webview the most simple way
i would like to load the webpage in the background so the user will not have a waiting time
maybe in a service running in the background or in a prevoius activity
i looked around the forums and could not find a refrence to the subject
help will be appriciated. 
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade the same problem a while ago, I know what you want. Asynctask! here is a good link I read on to get it to work!

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx

How you get it to work properly.
Load your webview in the doInBackground and perhaps a ProgressDialog that shows that your app i working?

GL mate

Answer (score 4):

You can set the webview's visibility to GONE and load the page and when onPageFinished is fired, you can then show the webview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: An onPageFinished event is fired when a HTML-code is loaded into a WebView. If later some JavaScript-code will run, a webpage will continue to create, it takes time. Visibility = GONE does not affect a time of loading (have just tested).

Answer (score 0):

you can use asynctaskLoader [take a look](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) it's better than the asynctask because it can manage the orientation changed and some other cool things...