# Background pre-loading of WebView cache

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I'd like to pre-load WebView's cache with a webpage from the internet.  This would need to be done asynchronously and hidden as to not disturb other UI interactions.  The purpose of the pre-load is to avoid subsequent network calls if the WebView is presented by way of optional button click (ultimately for speedier display).

The webpage contains Javascript and AJAX so I don't think pre-loading the cache using something like HttpClient would work.  I also looked at using WebView's loadUrl() in an AsyncTask but I am seeing this conflicts with the main UI thread.

Has anyone with a similar situation found a way to accomplish the background pre-loading/caching?

Comment: Did you find this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944546/android-webview-load-in-background

Answer (score 6):

`WebView` is loading data in a separate thread by default, so no need to use AsyncTask. Just create a hidden WebView and call `loadUrl()`.

If you want to pre-load more than one URL you can use a `WebViewClient` and override `onPageFinished()` to detect when the first one is completed. When you are done with the `WebView` make sure you remove references to it so that it can be garbage collected.

Finally, if you want to make sure that the visible `WebView` always uses the cached version of the url's when available, you can call:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK).
```