# Cache html contet to prepare it for display in WebView

Tags: java, android, html, caching, android-webview

I need to display html content in WebView control. Html content is served from rest webservice as string and it may contain images, css etc that must be loaded from server.

Obviously, I could let WebView to load all content automatically, but it's not good solution in my case. I need html content to be displayed immediately. So, before I load it into WebView I need to cache it first, probably just after webservice call and provide already cached data for display.

So I have question - what is simplest way to meet my requirements? Is there any built in mechsnism that I can use in my case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android webView Load in Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944546/android-webview-load-in-background)

Comment: not duplicate, I dont want webview to load content in background, instead I want to cache all neccesary data and provide already cached data to webview

Comment: @user1209216 have you found any solution or work arouund?

Answer (score 0):

please try [this](https://gist.github.com/jaydeepw/3594828) first and if it doesn't fit your needs you can go for some server side solutions like [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-html5mobile3/). as another way you can store your html content in database and use it as a cache, but you should think for a way to invalidate expired caches.

Comment: Server side solution is not possible. Also, I want to manage all html content by myself and force webview to always load cached data - even first load of new content should be made from cache